# How does one generically expand the argument of a gamma function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, expression-manipulation

I have expressions of the form

```
Gamma[2 (56 + k)]
```

which I would like to convert to

```
Gamma[112 + 2 k]
```

But

```
Gamma[2 (56 + k)] /. Gamma[x_] -> Gamma[Expand[x]]
```

leaves the function unchanged. So, what command should I employ?
(Rather elementary question, I presume.)

Comment: `Gamma[2 (56 + k)] /. Gamma[x_] :> Gamma[Expand[x]]` or `Expand /@ Gamma[2 (56 + k)]`

Comment: Or  `Gamma[2 (56 + k)] // ExpandAll `

Comment: Paul, please look carefully at the documentation of `->` and `:>`.

Comment: Well, it's fine with me if this is "put on hold", since my question has now been satisfactorily answered (for which I am certainly grateful to the responders, and to the existence of this particular stack exchange), thus, allowing me to immediately further pursue my  research topic. I certainly had realized that this was not the most challenging of questions, and that I could probably "dope" it out on my own--after some looking through the documentation, but to me this was certainly useful and a plus for the stack exchange, to my way of thinking.